# why checkbox wont check on page load?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following database table for the Compounds table (chemical compounds/elements in the periodic table) there are typos in table data so ignore them

[image]

the data is :

[image]

the controller :

```
    public class CheckboxController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Checkbox/
        testdbEntities db = new testdbEntities();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var comps = db.Compounds.Select(c => new CompoundModel { Id=c.Id, CompoundName=c.Name, IsSelected=c.IsSelected}).ToList();

            CheckboxVM cvm = new CheckboxVM { checkboxData=comps};

            return View(cvm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string Index(IEnumerable<CheckboxVM> collection)
        {
            return "";
        }
}
```

Model class CompoundModel is:

```
public class CompoundModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }


    public string CompoundName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

and the ViewModel CheckBoxVM:

```
public class CheckboxVM
{        
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CompoundNmae { get; set; }        
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }        
    public IEnumerable<CompoundModel> checkboxData { get; set; }   
}
```

When the page loads it should display check boxes with names and if db table has checked on them `(IsSelected=1)` then they should be checked.In the post back i need to receive the id, of the user checked `checkboxes`. At the moment my code does meet the first requirement to check the checked `checkboxes` based on `IsSelected` on page load. Is there a way to fix this?

If you need a video with debugging please ask i will be happy to post : )

**THE VIEW: (UPDATE)**

```
@model recitejs1.Models.CheckboxVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {   
        foreach (var item in Model.checkboxData)
        {



            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.IsSelected, (item.IsSelected)?new{@checked="check"}:null)@item.CompoundName

            @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id, item.Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.CompoundNmae, item.CompoundName)

        }
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Send" />
    }
```

Comment: You need to show your view.

Comment: And what is the purpose of `CheckboxVM`? The model you need to pass to the view need only be `IEnumerable<CompoundModel>` (and if you do need `CheckboxVM` then you POST method parameter should also be `CheckboxVM`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have updated my post!

Comment: @StephenMuecke i'm planning to extend the view so added a VM forehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls. It generates duplicate `name` attributes (that have no relationship to your model) and duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html).

Create a custom `EditorTemplate for your model

In `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CompoundModel.cshtml`

```
@model recitejs1.Models.CompoundModel
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CompoundName)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompoundName)
```

Then in the main view

```
@model recitejs1.Models.CheckboxVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.checkboxData)
  <input type="submit" name="name" value="Send" />
}
```

The `EditorFor()` method will generate the correct html for each item in your collection

Note: You should inspect the html before and after you make this change to better understand how model binding works.

Note also that your POST method parameter needs to be

```
public string Index(CheckboxVM model)
```

since that's what the view is based on. However the only property of `CheckboxVM` that you use in the view is `IEnumerable<CompoundModel> checkboxData` in which case your view should be

```
@model IEnumerable<CompoundModel>
...
@Html.EditorFor(m => m)
```

and keep the POST method as it is (but change the GET method)

Comment: so creating a custom template is the the commonly used way on this? and in what other UI controls related situations i need to create custom templates?

Comment: A custom `EditorTemplate` is the best approach. It correctly generates the correct html. It can be used for both a single instance and a collection of you model (the `EditorFor()` method accepts both `T` and `IEnumerable<T>`. You can create specific `EditorTemplates` for each controller (e.g. you can have a variation of this template in the `/View/anotherController/EditorTemplate/CompoundModel.cshtml` (the `EditorFor()` method first searches for a template in the controller folder, and if one is not found, it then searches the shared folder.